# What version of Seq to use with Node.js v0.4.7/Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a script that makes use of Seq, that I want to move to Heroku.

What version of the Seq library should I be using with Node 0.4.7 (which is what Heroku Cedar stack runs)?

https://github.com/substack/node-seq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seq's author says: Any version will do: https://twitter.com/#!/substack/status/114923523591520256

Because Seq doesn't use Node's APIs. Totally independent.